# Security on Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Using Socket.io what is the best way to require some sort of authentication for pushing to the socket. For example I have one group listeners who should only be allowed to received updates and I have admins who are allowed to push updates (and listen).

1. I could use some sort of passphrase that only the "admin" knows.
2. I could use separate sockets for pushing vs listening and block all listeners to the  pushing port
3. ?

Otherwise the listeners would just need to come up with some creative javascript in order to do the correct push. We can also assume that the server doesn't know if someone is an admin or a listner.

For example:

```
//Server
socket.on('foo', function (data) {      
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);
}

//listner client

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    alert("admin sent new update");
});


//admin client
someButton.onclick = sendMessage = function() {
    socket.emit('foo', {'update'});
};
```

Comment: Mhhh, could you not just add a check at every `socket.on` you want secured, for example: `if(!socket.authenticated) return;` and when you authenticate your user just define `socket.authenticated`

Comment: "We can also assume that the server doesn't know if someone is an admin or a listner." If this is the case, you're trusting the clients to behave on their own. You need *some* way for the server to authenticate users, even if it's stateless (like presenting a signed certificate).

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to know if you did authentication via the nodejs app itself or a different webserver. I created a gist for you where I use express.io where I had to secure all socket.emits from clients: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71462f414997ab114aa7 Good luck

Comment: In this situation, I don't want any of my 'users' to have emit privileges. Only my own admin server.

Comment: you could ignore the socket.io event for unauthorized users by checking if the user is authenticated. As for emit privileges from client-side eventually you can't do anything but just ignore it.

Comment: I think you should look for socket.io authorization functions